# 2014 SQL Server Suspect database

Tags: sql-server, columnstore

I had an evaluation version of SQL Server 2014.  It expired and I purchased a standard version of SQL Server 2014.  Unfortunately, during the evaluation period I created at least one columnstore index.  Probably multiple ones. My database is in suspect mode and tells me I must drop the columnstore index.  However, it won't let me drop it, because it's in suspect mode.

I can run sys.indexes but it doesn't show any indexes for the database in question.  I can't run DBCC CHECKDB.  I really don't want to pay for the next level up of SQL Server.

Comment: Maybe will help you http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2015/recovery-sql-server-suspect-mode/

Comment: Yes, I tried that.  I should have noted that when I try to alter the database to Emergency I get the same error message about the columnstore index

Comment: You can use a tsql to list all columnstore indexes http://raresql.com/2013/03/29/sql-server-list-of-all-indexes-with-column-name-and-datatype-including-columnstore-index/

Comment: I don't think that will work because I don't think it will allow me to even view or query even the table or index information from the table.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of, because standard edition does not allow column store indexes, is to do the following.

EDIT: Totally forgot about backwards compatibility, answer updated.

1. Stop SQL Server service using your configuration manager in order
   to copy your mdf and ldf files for the database to a different
   location
2. Try to download another SQL Server 2014 evaluation and create a new instance
   on your local machine.
3. Attach your copied mdf and ldf files on the SQL Server 2014
   evaluation instance and then remove the columnstore indexes from all
   your tables.  Be sure to change your compatibility level to SQL
   Server 2014 if not already for the database.
4. Stop the SQL Server service on 2014 evaluation or detach the database and
   copy those files back to your 2014 Standard instance, replacing the old ones.
5. Start the SQL Server instance on your 2014 Standard edition and
   hopefully you will be up and running.  If this works, be sure to backup your database and start a backup maintenance plan.

Hope this helps!

Comment: sounds like a great idea.  I'll let you know how it goes.  thanks

Comment: Scratch downloading the 2016 evaluation, I forgot you can not attach because of backwards compatibility.  Try to get another 2014 evaluation instead.  I will update my answer, sorry about that.